# Why do I have to edit /etc/hosts just sometimes when using nginx-ingress controller and resources in my local k8s environment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Not sure if this is OS specific, but on my M1 Mac, I'm installing the Nginx controller and resource example located in the official [Quick Start guide for the controller.](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start) for Docker Desktop for Mac. The instructions are as follows:

```
// Create the Ingress
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace

// Pre-flight checks
kubectl get pods --namespace=ingress-nginx

kubectl wait --namespace ingress-nginx \
  --for=condition=ready pod \
  --selector=app.kubernetes.io/component=controller \
  --timeout=120s

// and finally, deploy and test the resource.
kubectl create deployment demo --image=httpd --port=80
kubectl expose deployment demo

kubectl create ingress demo-localhost --class=nginx \
  --rule=demo.localdev.me/*=demo:80

kubectl port-forward --namespace=ingress-nginx service/ingress-nginx-controller 8080:80
```

I noticed that the instructions did not mention having to edit the `/etc/hosts` file, which I found strange. And, when I tested it by putting `demo.localdev.me:8080` into the browser, it did work as expected!

But why? What happened that an application inside of a docker container was able to influence behavior on my host machine and intercept its web traffic without me having to edit the `/etc/hosts` file?

For my next test, I re-executed everything above with the only change being that I switched `demo` to `demo2`. That did **not** work. I did have to go into `/etc/hosts` and add `demo2.localdev.me 127.0.0.1` as an entry. After that both demo and demo2 work as expected.

Why is this happening? Not having to edit the /etc/hosts file is appealing. Is there a way to configure it so that they all work? How would I turn it "off" from happening automatically if I needed to route traffic back out to the internet rather than my local machine?

Comment: Did you create also separate service `demo2`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I replicated your issue and got a similar behaviour on the Ubuntu 20.04.3 OS.

The problem is that [NGINX Ingress controller Local testing guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#local-testing) did not mention that [`demo.localdev.me` address points to `127.0.0.1`](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3ademo.localdev.me&run=toolpage) - that's why it works without editing `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/resolve.conf` file. Probably it's something like [`*.localtest.me` addresses](https://readme.localtest.me/):

> Here’s how it works. The entire domain name localtest.me—and all wildcard entries—point to 127.0.0.1. So without any changes to your host file you can immediate start testing with a local URL.

Also good and detailed explanation in [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/1280827/why-does-the-registered-domain-name-localtest-me-resolve-to-127-0-0-1).

So Docker Desktop / Kubernetes change nothing on your host.

The [address `demo2.localdev.me` also points to `127.0.0.1`](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3ademo2.localdev.me&run=toolpage), so it should work as well for you - and as I tested in my environment the behaviour was exactly the same as for the `demo.localdev.me`.

You may run [`nslookup` command](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mac-os-x/0596003706/re315.html) and check which IP address is pointed to the specific domain name, for example:

```
user@shell:~$ nslookup demo2.localdev.me
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   demo2.localdev.me
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

You may try to do some tests with other hosts name, like some existing ones or no-existing then of course it won't work because the address won't be resolved to the `127.0.0.1` thus it won't be forwarded to the Ingress NGINX controller. In these cases, you can edit `/etc/hosts` (as you did) or use [`curl` flag `-H`](https://riptutorial.com/curl/example/31719/change-the--host---header), for example:

I created the ingress using following command:

```
kubectl create ingress demo-localhost --class=nginx --rule=facebook.com/*=demo:80
```

Then I started port-forwarding and I run:

```
user@shell:~$ curl -H "Host: facebook.com" localhost:8080
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

You wrote:

> For my next test, I re-executed everything above with the only change being that I switched `demo` to `demo2`. That did **not** work. I did have to go into `/etc/hosts` and add `demo2.localdev.me 127.0.0.1` as an entry. After that both demo and demo2 work as expected.

Well, that sounds strange, could you run `nslookup demo2.localdev.me` without adding an entry in the `/etc/hosts` and then check? Are you sure you performed the correct query before, did you not change something on the Kubernetes configuration side? As I tested (and presented above), it should work exactly the same as for `demo.localdev.me`.