# Kubernetes: how an ingress domain is resolved to localhost on windows

Tags: windows, kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress

Following https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#installation-guide

```
kubectl create deployment demo --image=httpd --port=80
kubectl expose deployment demo
kubectl create ingress demo-localhost --class=nginx \
  --rule="demo.localdev.me/*=demo:80"
kubectl port-forward --namespace=ingress-nginx service/ingress-nginx-controller 8080:80
```

how the domain "demo.localdev.me" is resolved to localhost?

```
 > curl http://demo.localdev.me:8080
 <html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

The domain "demo.localdev.me" is not in the c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file on windows 11. Is it added to a DNS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain names or IP addresses on a local computer can be resolved by adding entries in the local hosts file on a computer (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` → for windows) . Go to this path and set up the hostname.

Before adding it check if the dns is already configured by using `nslookup host_name`.If you don’t find it in dns you need to add it.

As per [official doc](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/#known-issues):

> The ingress, and ingress-dns addons are currently only supported on
> Linux.

If you have already used `minikube addons enable ingress`, Try `minikube tunnel` and your ingress resources would be available at `127.0.0.1`. So the requests from `http://demo.localdev.me:8080` will be sent to `127.0.0.1`.

Refer to the [official doc](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/addons/ingress-dns/) and [blog](https://snehalhingane1998.medium.com/configuring-dns-server-for-kubernetes-clusters-384cddb4f11d) authored by Snehalhingane for more information.

Comment: the domain demo.localdev.me is not in the hosts file, but it is resolved to 127.0.0.1.  ping demo.localdev.me, Pinging demo.localdev.me [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data. Trying to understand how this works. thanks.

Comment: For that information please check this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1280827/why-does-the-registered-domain-name-localtest-me-resolve-to-127-0-0-1) and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70531119/why-do-i-have-to-edit-etc-hosts-just-sometimes-when-using-nginx-ingress-control) which has detailed information.